# How to use AsyncTask. how to call it and how to create a db instance for the entire application?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I have a class called DBAsyncTask using AsyncTask which is depricated, then how should I do that.

```
class DBAsyncTask(val context: Context, val restaurantEntity: RestaurantEntity, val mode: Int) :
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {


val db = Room.databaseBuilder(context, RestaurantDatabase::class.java, "restaurant-db").build()

override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): Boolean {

    when (mode) {

        1 -> {
            val restaurant: RestaurantEntity =
                db.restaurantDao().getAllRestaurant(restaurantEntity.restaurant_Id)
            db.close()
            return restaurant != null

        }

        2 -> {
            db.restaurantDao().insertRestaurant(restaurantEntity)
            db.close()
            return true

        }

        3 -> {
            db.restaurantDao().deleteRestaurant(restaurantEntity)
            db.close()
            return true
        }
    }
    return false    }
```

Also, I used it like this, which isn't the correct way to do it.

```
val checkFav = DBAsyncTask(context, restaurantEntity, 1).execute()
        val isFav = checkFav.get()
```

> Database instance should be created once for the whole application and
> the reference should be used everywhere

How should I implement this ???

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a better option if you need to rewrite this and use Kotlin/Room [room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room).

Another option is to use [Singleton](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/singleton) pattern, and if you use Kotlin you can use [Coroutines](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines?gclid=CjwKCAjwuvmHBhAxEiwAWAYj-JcZWu1ywibgKqdTOrg3h4_5VL6OI_cszsFLT2H98JLG5JTWBoQ0oxoCk04QAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) together or [Task](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/tasks/Task) if use Java.

I believe that Singleton or Monostate can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create singleton class for getting db instance. May be some thing like this.

```
public class DbBuilder{

private static Builder databaseBuilder = null;

public static Builder getInstance() {

    if(databaseBuilder == null)
    {
        databaseBuilder  = Room.databaseBuilder(context, 
        RestaurantDatabase::class.java, "restaurant-db").build()  // create your dbBuilder here
        return databaseBuilder;
    }
    else 
    {

        return databaseBuilder;
    }
}
}
```

And then you can call this in your code like this

```
 val db = DbHelper.getInstance()
```

Comment: Then how should I use AsyncTask here